# how to check a data has been added into the database table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL trigger that automatically insert a data into a table after a data has been added into the other table.. is there code in PHP to check whether the data has been inserted or not by the trigger?

in the PHP code, I put setInterval function to refresh the page every second. I just want the page stop refreshing after a data has been inserted by the trigger...

Comment: check for `count(*)` and keep running your code. if there is an increase in `count(*)` use `clearInterval`;

Comment: Why are you using a trigger when you clearly do not trust it to do the very thing that it is designed to? Also, the trigger should be processed in the same transaction in which the INSERT happens. Polling for one second is a waste of a second.

Comment: @susheel in MySQL, count(id) is a lot faster than count(*).

Comment: @susheel Your idea make sense.. I've tried make it but fail.. If you don't mind, could you suggest me the algorithm to check if there was increment in a variable..??

Comment: Take two `variables`. In the first variable store the value of rows intially, when you load the page. `other variable` just initialize it to 0. When you make an ajax call for first time store the value in the second variable(`use global scope`) and compare if its equal with first variable. Do the comparison on every ajax call and you can decide whether a row was added.

you can even get the number of rows which were added since the page loaded by subracting. 

`variable2 - variable1`

Answer (score 0):

If your trigger fails, your db will do a rollback and the first insert query will fail. So just check if the first query succeeded / you are not getting any errors.